# Text is off center with \begin{center}

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Using this source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vim omnes munere at, no affert appetere
cotidieque ius. Quo nulla elaboraret cu. Nec petentium maiestatis
accommodare at, velit perfecto accommodare cu eos. Quo natum explicari te,
duo ei facilis maiorum. Nonumes dolorem pro ad, quo te quod maiorum.
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The left margin is about 30 pixels more than the right margin. How can I make it
truly centered, or at least closer?

Comment: I'm guessing you are in Europe so using A4 paper? In that case, `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`: the standard layout settings are for letter paper, but the stock size depends on your installation choices.

Comment: For test add to your MWE `\usepackage{showframe} and than look, if your text is in center between shown text borders

Comment: @StevenPenny In that case, add `letterpaper` as an option and load `graphicx`: again, this will make sure any installation settings aren't interfering.

Comment: @StevenPenny `\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}\usepackage{graphicx}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including *geometry* fixed it:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
```

Or by setting *pdfpage* sizes:

```
\pdfpagewidth 8.5in
\pdfpageheight 11in
```

Comment: If you use TeX Live, you can configure your installation via `tlmgr` to recognize whether letterpaper or A4 should be the default.